# nginx redirect everything except one location

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect everything from http or https  dom1.com to dom2.com EXCEPT for dom1.com/api/auth

Here's what I have in my nginx config

```
server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dom1.com;
        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://dom2.com$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        location /api/auth/ {

        }
}
```

Unfortunately it's redirecting the dom1.com/api/auth to dom2.com - How can I re work this to get everything but dom1.com/api/auth to redirect?

Comment: Add `location /api/auth`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where you want to direct all the traffic going to /api/auth/ but if the below will send everything to dom2 except /api/auth/ which it sends to dom1

```
   server{
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name dom1.com;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://dom2.com$request_uri? permanent;
            }

            location /api/auth/ {
                    proxy_pass https://dom1.com
            }
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, going to dom1.com does not redirect to dom2.com - :\

Comment: Can you post your whole nginx.conf file?